# Behaviour on different computers

Tags: discussion, policy

Whilst answering questions, is it Ok to use functions/bits of code where the output will be different for some computers?

For example I was thinking about adding a new time type to PYKE where the input could be in the form natively used by the computer ([see here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior))

> %c - Locale’s appropriate date and time representation.
>
> Tue Aug 16 21:30:00 1988 (en_US);
>   Di 16 Aug 21:30:00 1988 (de_DE)

This means that the code would be valid on some running computers but not others.

A more extreme variation of this could be a variant of the as of now standard loophole, [Using MetaGolfScript](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5076/32686) but using something like the MAC address as the identifier. This could potentially allow any program (pyth for example) under 7 bytes long to be a zero byte answer in MAC-lang, which executes pyth code with your MAC address as input.

Should this type of input be allowed by default?

(Note should not be an answer for [Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/32686) because this form of input isn't a stream/form of input)

Comment: I would say "Yes," given the answers here -- http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5851/42963

Comment: [Very much related](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/7881/194)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question splits into two parts. The first part asks about locales: this issue has already been discussed in [an earlier question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7881/194), and there seems to be a qualified majority consensus that it's ok for answers to be locale-dependent as long as that is clearly documented.

The second part I would describe as asking about answers which take the piss. If someone did create a language which uses something like the MAC address to outsource part of their source code, I would consider that it violates the [Outsourcing the real answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1085/194) standard loophole, as well as the spirit of the [Using MetaGolfScript](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5076/194) standard loophole, and so I would downvote and either flag as low quality or vote to delete.